# Nested class definition in Abstract Base Class (C++)

Tags: c++

Are there any suggestions on how to use a nested class <strike>iterator</strike>
 in an [ABC](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/abcs.html) in C++ ? Note that, I also want to have a virtual function returning an
instance of this class.

More specifically here's my approach:

```
class ABC {
        typedef iterator<forward_iterator_tag, MyType> MyTypeIter;
        virtual MyTypeIter *begin() = 0;
};

class Foo : ABC {
        MyTypeIter : public ABC::MyTypeIter;
        virtual MyTypeIter *begin();
};

ABC::MyTypeIter *Foo::begin()
{
        Foo::MyTypeIter *ret;
        ret = new Foo::MyTypeIter(...);
        return ret;
}
```

Is there a better approach than this (e.g. one that does not use pointers) ?

Answer (score 1):

What is your problem? A nested class behaves the same way as a top-level class, so you may return its objects just as you would have returned any other.

Comment: The virtual function in the implementation function needs to match the ABC definition.

Comment: Sure, the same thing as if MyTypeIter was a top-level class. If you want to have a class hierarchy for iterators, then you will have to return a pointer from function, otherwise the returned value will be sliced when you assign it to ABC:MyIterType (the effect when an instance of a derived class is assigned to an instance of a base class).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on how iterators are implemented for std::vector class, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to keep *iterators* interal to the class and exposing only an interface for iteration.
For example, you can implement a `List<>` with the methods:

- `void prepare_iteration() // reset the internal iterator`
- `bool step_iteration() // move internal iterator`
- `DATA_TYPE & read() // return the data by using the iterator`
- `write( DATA_TYPE & ) // update the data by using the iterator`

In this example the iterator can be a simple node pointer and it's never exposed to the user.
I find this approach much easier and safer than iterator objects.
(well the 'safer' part  needs a lot of discussion)

1. The above interface can be implemented as an abstract class.
2. Your *container* (or whatever) classes can inherit it and implement it.

I know that's not the answer that you are looking for but it's just an alternative idea to design your classes.

Comment: I've thought about that, but my problem is that you can't have two different iteratators iterating over the same object.

Comment: This approach has a bit of a Not Implemented Here feel to it. Iterators were created to present a unified approach to iterating through containers. Rolling your own iterators is not going to make it easier for people to understand your code and you won't be able to participate in constructs like std::for_each.

This approach also prevents multi-threaded interaction with your container

Comment: @ynimous:  Yes I know it and it's about the 'safe' part. It's tricky (IMO) to have simultaneously iterations (and modifications) to the same object.

Comment: @Eric, it's just an alternative. I did not say *never* implement iterators. BTW, I have implemented a for_each for the above abstract interface.